# MongoDB $elemsMatch in practice

Tags: mongodb

These are my documents:

```
[
  {
    uuid: 1,
    emailNotifications: [
      {
        targetEmailAddress: "w@w.pl"
      },
      {
        targetEmailAddress: "w2@w.pl"
      }      
    ]
  },
  {
    uuid: 2,
    emailNotifications: [
      {
        targetEmailAddress: "xxxw@w.pl"
      },
      {
        targetEmailAddress: "xxxw2@w.pl"
      },   
    ]
  },
]
```

I want query those with emailNotifications.targetEmailAddress equals to "w@w.pl":

```
db.collection.find({
  emailNotifications: {
    $elemMatch: {
      targetEmailAddress: "w@wp.pl"
    }
  }
})
```

but it finds nothing. Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Your value of `targetEmailAdress` in the query is wrong. You don't have `w@wp.pl` in your documents.